# Are 'avail + oneself + to-phrase' or ' 'avail + to + NP'' ever acceptable?

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

My instructor put this in his course materials:

> Although this is an online class where you can avail yourself to your textbook etc.

Is there any circumstance in which "avail to [object]" would be correct?

I checked [Oxford (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/avail) and did not find any examples with "to," but I wanted to double-check.

Comment: It was meant to use *of* instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avail+yourself+of%2Cavail+yourself+to&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests that this usage is extremely rare compared to using "avail oneself *of*." It is certainly attested, [as a Google Books search shows,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22avail%20yourself%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) but not enough to be considered standard.

As an aside: as [Cambridge notes,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/avail) in Indian English "avail" can mean "to make use of something," so in that dialect the following sentence would be valid:

> Over a thousand learners have already availed the opportunity to study at our college.

That said, this isn't really a case of "avail + NP + to-phrase," since "to study at our college" is just an infinitival clause within the NP "the opportunity to study at our college."

Answer (score -2):

It’s as much acceptable as literally meaning figuratively used to be basically no, but you can say to no avail.
To say avail to is like saying help to it doesn’t make any sense.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/avail. You can also say an idiom avail of or avail one/yourself of meaning to use an available resource to your advantage.

Comment: Could you give your post a little proofreading?  It's hard for me to follow -- there might be some extra words, or some words missing.