# Is 'it avails to' ok to mean 'it is useful to'?

Tags: word-usage

When trying to say 'it is useful/helpful/beneficial' to, for example, remember something, is 'it avails to remember' a structure that is/can be used?
Would 'it serves to remember' be better?

Many thanks!

Comment: Technically it can be used but doesn't really sound natural. "It serves to remember" sounds better but the simpler "it's useful to remember" sounds best.

Comment: Using [*avail oneself*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/avail-of?q=avail+of+something) is quite formal, and doesn't sit well in a text that seems rather conversational in style. Also [avail](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/avail) *(verb)* says "old use". I could say "I will avail myself of a sandwich" but it would be homourously.

Comment: [Are 'avail + oneself + to-phrase' or ' 'avail + to + NP'' ever acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521068/is-avail-to-ever-acceptable) is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Lambie 1836   J. Gilbert "Christian Atonement" iii. 96   *No ingenuity can avail to confound them.* The *to* is a preposition not a particle = in order to.

Comment: @Lambie can you please provide citation for this claim?

Comment: _Can avail_ requires a modal. We're into deep waters here. Also, where does the _it_ dummy come from? Extraposition of what?

Answer (score 1):

> (SOED) **1** *v.i. & t.* Be of use, help, value, or advantage, (*to*); have efficacy, profit. Middle English

[image]

This construction of "avail" is becoming increasingly rare; it's been found a lot in the religious literature, and still is, but to a much lesser extent; however, although more suited for formal writing, apparently, it can still be used.

([Commentary on Romans — John Calvin · 2012](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Commentary_on_Romans/puS0DAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&pg=PT26&printsec=frontcover)) It ought then to be reverenced and honored, since veneration is due to God's power; and as it avails to our salvation, it ought to be loved by us.

([The Pulpit Commentary, Volume 8 — Spence-Jones, Henry · 2015](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Pulpit_Commentary_Volume_8/91xfCgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&pg=PT1476&printsec=frontcover)) It avails to take away that surest foe of all to sanctification, trust in self, at one stroke, but a stroke that must be felt life's length.

([Mother's Remedies: Over One Thousand Tried and Tested — Thomas Jefferson Ritter · 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Mother_s_Remedies_Over_One_Thousand_Trie/nRSvEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&pg=PT41&printsec=frontcover)) The real value of any book, or what is sometimes called its intrinsic value, or utility, consists in what it avails to gratify some desire or want of our nature. It depends, then, wholly upon its qualities in relation to our desires.

([Negligence and Compensation Cases Annotated - 1950](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Negligence_and_Compensation_Cases_Annota/YBYnAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22it+avails+to%22&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&printsec=frontcover) )  Therefore it avails to bar subsequent recovery of damages

([Transactions - Volume 3 - American Association for the Study and Prevention of Infant Mortality · 1913 · ‎](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Transactions/WThYAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22it+avails+to%22&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&printsec=frontcover))   Whether it avails to do this work I do not know.

([Princeton University Bulletin - Francis Landey Patton, ‎Howard Crosby Butler, ‎Varnum Lansing Collins · 1901](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Princeton_University_Bulletin/lNQ6AQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22it+avails+to%22&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&printsec=frontcover))   Life is not long enough , imperfect , because while it avails to prove the fact  that classical culture bears a radical relation to modern culture , it does not necessarily prove the

([The Baptist Quarterly — Henry G. Weston · 2022](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Baptist_Quarterly/uJ1fEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&pg=PA54&printsec=frontcover) It avails to lift the load of guilt . It brings man and God together in the person of a Redeemer . It works justification through the economy of divine suffering and sacrifice . Here emphatically Christianity is Christ ;

([The System of Doctrines, contained in Divine Relation, ... — Samuel Hopkins · 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_System_of_Doctrines_contained_in_Div/x3cnDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22it+avails+to%22&pg=PA185&printsec=frontcover)) What the Redeemer has done and suffered is imputed to him; that is, is reckoned in his favour, so that he has the benefit of it, as much as if it were his own; and it avails to obtain deliverance, from the curse of the law, for him, ...